# Why do I get this error define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php

I have been following a course,

Here are all the errors I get:

> **Warning**:  defined() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given
> in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\photo_gallery\includes\initialize.php**
> on line **5**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Use of undefined
> constant SITE_ROOT - assumed 'SITE_ROOT' in
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\photo_gallery\includes\initialize.php** on
> line **7**
>  
>  **Warning**:
> require_once(SITE_ROOT\includes\config.php): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory in
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\photo_gallery\includes\initialize.php** on
> line **9**
>  
>  **Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed
> opening required 'SITE_ROOT\includes\config.php'
> (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\photo_gallery\includes\initialize.php** on
> line **9**

**My Code:**

```
define('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

define('SITE_ROOT') ? null :
define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'sample'.DS.'samples'.DS.'samples'.DS.'samples');

define('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'function.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'user.php');
```

Comment: shouldn't you use [`defined`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) instead?

Comment: I do that gives me more error.

Comment: Now those errors are gone.

Comment: Like Ghost said, define is for constants http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php while defined is as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php - `defined('CONSTANT') or define('CONSTANT', 'SomeDefaultValue');`

Comment: But now i get this one again:

Comment: defined() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Comment: define('SITE_ROOT') ? null : is wrong? What line is the error about?

Comment: Line 5. That is the error line.

Comment: it looks like you have them back to front

Comment: using defined fixes the same error for me :) 
there is a difference between define https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php 
and 
defined https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your defines with the below

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :
define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'sample'.DS.'samples'.DS.'samples'.DS.'samples');
defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
```

Comment: Yes using defined and null check is resolving the issue and error is gone. Appreciate it.